# React - Change onClick behaviour based on history.location.path with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that returns a function, but I want it to return one of two functions depending on the current URL (one button - does two things depending on where you are).

Here is what the button does currently:

```
const showApplyButton = () => {
    return (
      <button onClick={addToCart} className="btn btn-outline-info mt-2 mb-2">
          Apply 
      </button>
    );
  };
```

I would like the onClick to return a different function depending on the current URL.

My attempt was:

```
  const applyButtonBehaviour = (history) => {
  if(history.location.pathname === "/Cart") {
    console.log("Hello world");
  } else {addToCart(history)};
};

  const showApplyButton = (history) => {
    return (
      <button onClick={applyButtonBehaviour(history)} className="btn btn-outline-info mt-2 mb-2">
          Apply 
      </button>
    );
  };
```

The above uses

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and

```
export default withRouter(Card);
```

To pass down the history.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

[image]

The error goes away when I revert back to my original "non-conditional" solution that only exhibits one behavior regardless of the current location/path.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the problem is an infinite render loop. When the component renders the `button`, it's immediately invoking `onClick={applyButtonBehaviour(history)}`. When the `applyButtonBehaviour` function is invoked, it's immediately invoking the `console.log` or the `addToCart`.

Assuming `addToCart` itself is doing something that triggers a re-render (state update, etc). When the component re-renders, it calls all these methods again getting stuck in an infinite render loop. If you only want this to happen on click, you should wrap the click handler in a function to be invoked only when clicked (not immediately on render).

There are two options:

```
<button onClick={() => applyButtonBehaviour(history)} ...>
```

or

```
const applyButtonBehaviour = (history) => () => { ... };
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, the solution was a really inane error and unfortunately I can't delete my question.